# Make many lines in one layer (Python)

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, line

I what to create many lines with this code:

```
v_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "cable", "memory")
pr = v_layer.dataProvider()
seg = QgsFeature()
seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([line_start, geomPoint]))
pr.addFeatures( [ seg ] )
v_layer.updateExtents()
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([v_layer])
```

Buth this create one layer for each of this code.

How can I create all in one layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add all the geometries before the addMapLayers

```
v_layer = QgsVectorLayer("LineString", "cable", "memory")
pr = v_layer.dataProvider()
# first element
seg = QgsFeature()
seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([line_start, geomPoint]))
pr.addFeatures( [ seg ] )
v_layer.updateExtents()
# second element
seg = QgsFeature()
seg.setGeometry(QgsGeometry.fromPolyline([geomPoint, newgeomPoint]))
pr.addFeatures( [ seg ] )
v_layer.updateExtents()
# etc
......
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([v_layer])
```

so use a for loop

Comment: @user1573901 Please upvote useful answers and accept answers that solve your problem (by clicking the tick mark on the left).